# VB.NET listbox won't display list items

Tags: vb.net

```
    lstSafaris.DataSource = Nothing
    lstSafaris.Items.Clear()
    lstSafaris.Refresh()
    lstSafaris.Items.Add("No unclosed safaris")
    lstSafaris.DrawMode = DrawMode.Normal
    Try
        Helpers.openConnection(sqlConn)

        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("closingTables", sqlConn)
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim sqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
        sqlDA.Fill(sqlDS)

        For counter As Integer = 0 To sqlDS.Tables(1).Rows.Count - 1
            listSource.Add(sqlDS.Tables(1).Rows(counter).Item("allocation_id"), sqlDS.Tables(1).Rows(counter).Item("file_number"))
        Next

        If listSource.Count > 0 Then
            lstSafaris.DataSource = New BindingSource(listSource, Nothing)
            lstSafaris.ValueMember = "Key"
            lstSafaris.DisplayMember = "Value"
        End If
        lstSafaris.Refresh()

        sqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End Try
```

So guys that is my code for the Listbox, this is a Sub that is called when the program is launched and whenever the whole form is refreshed, so when the problem first runs it works fine but the problem is when the form is refreshed, it displays count is greater than one but its blank, it's like all the items are there but they are not displayed, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
  If listSource.Count > 0 Then
            lstSafaris.DataSource = New BindingSource(listSource, Nothing)
            lstSafaris.ValueMember = "Key"
            lstSafaris.DisplayMember = "Value"
            lstSafaris.DataBind()
  End If
```

you need to bind the data and not need to refresh data or clear the Items just remove data source before assign any data to data source as shown below.

```
   lstSafaris.DataSource = Nothing
```

Comment: I tried just setting only datasource to nothing and reassigning it back again, it didn't work, same issue

Answer (score 0):

If blank spots are showing up then it would seem like the binding is there, but the data isn't. I would do a quick-watch on your listsource dictionary after populating it and make sure that it is filled with data. If it has data then your

```
lstSafaris.ValueMember = "Key"
lstSafaris.DisplayMember = "Value"
lstSafaris.DataSource = New BindingSource(listSource, Nothing)
```

should work